# C++ server require ajax call to connect twice

Tags: javascript, c++, ajax, windows, http

I have created simple c++ http server that accept post request and parses its data.

```
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 4096
#define DEFAULT_PORT "8080"



class CHttp {
public:
    CHttp() {
        recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
        iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != 0) {
            printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);      
        }
        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
        iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
        if (iResult != 0) {
            printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
            WSACleanup();
        }
    }

    int init() {
        ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
        if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        freeaddrinfo(result);

        iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void acceptConnection() {
        cout << "Starting to listen " << endl;
        ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
        if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
        cout << "Listening " << endl;
        dataHandler();
    }

    void dataHandler() {
        bool isDoneLoadingData = false; // flag to break outer loop of loading data
        char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN]; // data will be loaded here
        map<string, string > headers;
        int superPosition = 0;
        cout << "begin" << endl;
        do {
            iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf + superPosition , DEFAULT_BUFLEN - superPosition, 0);
            cout << "Iresult " << iResult << endl;
            string tmp_buff(recvbuf,iResult+superPosition);
            size_t index;
            size_t bytesCount = 0;
            while( (index = tmp_buff.find("\r\n")) != string::npos ) {
                if (tmp_buff[0] == '\r' && tmp_buff [1] == '\n') { 
                    size_t content_length = atoi(headers["Content-Length:"].c_str());
                    int spareData = tmp_buff.size() - 2; // check spare data in buffer;
                    int dataLoad = content_length - spareData;
                    if (!dataLoad) {
                        headers.insert(make_pair("data", tmp_buff.substr(2)));
                    }
                    else {
                        char *otherData = new char[content_length];
                        memcpy(otherData, tmp_buff.substr(2).c_str(), spareData);
                        int t = recv(ClientSocket, otherData + spareData , content_length - spareData, 0);
                        headers.insert(make_pair("data", string(otherData, content_length)));
                    }
                    isDoneLoadingData = true;
                    break;          
                }

                string tmp_header_line = tmp_buff.substr(0, index);
                int pos = tmp_header_line.find_first_of(' ');
                headers.insert(std::make_pair( tmp_header_line.substr(0,pos),tmp_header_line.substr(pos)));
                bytesCount += tmp_header_line.size() + 2;
                tmp_buff = tmp_buff.substr(index + 2);
            }
            if (isDoneLoadingData) break;
            memmove(recvbuf, recvbuf + bytesCount, ( iResult + superPosition) - bytesCount );
            superPosition = ( iResult + superPosition ) - bytesCount;

        } while (iResult > 0);
        for (auto &a : headers)
            cout << a.first << a.second << endl;
        cout << "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" << endl;

        return;
    }


private:
    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    int recvbuflen;
    int iResult;
    WSADATA wsaData;
};

int main()
{
    CHttp server;
    if (server.init()) {
        cout << "Error occured " << endl;
    }

        server.acceptConnection();

    return 0;
}
```

I am using postman to test it. So far i have found no problem using postman ( it does support file posting yet ). However i tried to create simple Chrome extension that posts data to this server:

var url  = document.getElementById("url");

```
var butt = document.getElementById("button");
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    url.value = tab.url;
});


    butt.addEventListener('click', function(){
        loadDoc();
      });

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
}
```

Invoking ajax call, server starts to "listen" , but no data are sent. I need to invoke the ajax call second time in order to data to be sent which is not way ajax call should behave.

I have found nothing that would indicate what could cause this. Has anyone met same problem as this? Why is this happening and how could i fix this?

Thanks for help.

Comment: are you running into CORS?

Comment: i doubt, as i said when i invoke ajax call twice it sends data.

Comment: CORS will issue an `OPTIONS` request first.

Comment: but it means it sends some data to server,  if it happened it read some data which did not happened. Also second time i invoke function all headers gets printed and option is not one of them. Please correct me if i missunderstood it.